# Display screen on Lenovo Yoga 510 laptop randomly powers off

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, crash, power-management, unresponsive

Helping a friend.

The laptop screen on Lenovo Yoga 510 goes blank randomly. The light by the power socket and the light by the power switch remain lit. Battery at about 80% charge. The machine does not respond to the keyboard in this state. I can restart the machine by holding in the power switch for a number of seconds. I have tried to hear the fans and they appear to be on but not blasting away. Laptop keyboard and base don't feel hot to the touch. I have uninstalled Classic shell. I have run several benchmarks such as Prime95, Cinebench, Heaven to try to load the CPU and cause the temperature to rise. I can't cause the machine to crash when I am running the benchmarks to try to stress the machine CPU.

I was thinking this was some kind of power supply/power delivery/ overheating/ cooling failure problem.

I have decided to perform a clean install of Windows 10, and reinstall the benchmark/stress test software, then try to recreate the problem. Problem is there seems to be no pattern to the crash I can discern so far. I can use the machine as my daily machine for about a week so I can see if the crash happens again after a clean install and try to discern a pattern.

Do the symptoms suggest a problem or is Lenovo laptops known for this? I might just sell the machine for parts if it is not possible to diagnose the problem.

Comment: “The laptop screen on Lenovo Yoga 510 goes blank randomly. The light by the power socket and the light by the power switch remain lit.” This doesn’t sound like a software issue. It sounds like the cable connecting the display to the laptop motherboard itself is loose. Seeing that the display is one of those displays that that fold way back, my guess is that it is definitely a display cable connection issue.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Now that makes sense. I will use it as my desktop machine with an external monitor plugged in. Then bend the display at hinges and see if external monitor stays on but internal laptop display goes off.